# Sharepoint 2016 online workflows

Tags: workflow, approval

Is it possible to enable more than two Sharepoint 2010 workflow templates (like approval workflow and etc.)  in SP 2016 Online, without Designer 2013.
At Manage Site Features I have options stated belows:

- Duet Enterprise - SAP Workflow - Deactivate
- Project Proposal Workflow - Deactivate
- SAP Workflow Web Parts - Deactivate
- Workflow Task Content Type - Deactivate
- Workflows can use app permissions - - Deactivate

(Workflow Health) is connected:

[image]
[image]

## Edit

Thanks, But I need apologize for the poorly question. The thing is that I can't add others workflows templates in my SP online. And I can't figure out is it not  capable or something is turned off.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Each will get activated once you create them. Right now you have 2 active from the screenshot. But only one of them is being executed and the other is not. This does not mean the "Equipment Installation" is deactivated. What it means is that the parameters you set for it have not been met, or its work has already been completed. The "0" means no work remains for this workflow.